# AngularJS Routing to different page with different controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two HTML pages. One is the `exam.html` and other is `result.html`. On certain condition in the controller `ExamCtrl` of exam.html, I route to `result.html` using `$location.path`. But however, on the `result` page, the controller `ResultCtrl` doesn't seem to load though I have added it in the config file.

angular config file:

```
angular.module('exam').config(['$stateProvider',
  function ($stateProvider) {
    // Exam state routing
    $stateProvider
      .state('exam', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/exam',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
      })
      .state('exam.list', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'modules/exam/client/views/exam.client.view.html',
        controller: 'ExamCtrl'
      })
      .state('/result', {
        url: '/result',
        templateUrl: 'modules/exam/client/views/exam-result.client.view.html',
        contoller: 'ResultCtrl'
      });
  }
]);
```

ExamCtrl:

```
angular
.module('exam')
.controller('ExamCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', '$http',
  function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, $http) {


$scope.submitAnswer = function (selected) {         
      //some code
      if (qtnCounter > 5) {
        // loads the result page.
        $location.path('/result');
      } else {
        $scope.getQues();
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

ResultCtrl:

```
angular
.module('exam')
.controller('ResultCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', '$http',
  function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, $http) {

    console.log('ResultCtrl');

   }
]);
```

result.html:

```
<body ng-controller="ResultCtrl">
    <h1>Result page!</h1>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of using `$location` use the `$state` to change to a given state in your app.

Inject the `$state` in the controller and then call the `transitionTo()` which will load the view and setup the controller

```
angular
.module('exam')
.controller('ExamCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Authentication', '$http',
  function ($scope, $state, Authentication, $http) {


$scope.submitAnswer = function (selected) {         
      //some code
      if (qtnCounter > 5) {
        // loads the result page.
        $state.transitionTo('/result');
      } else {
        $scope.getQues();
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Np, happy coding:)